# siblings() in jQuery doesn't work for table tr elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a big table, with main tr-element and second
I need hide/show not all together, just only subling
But this js code doesnt work

Sorry for russian words))) Its not imprortant i sure

```js
$(".tr-main").click(function() {
  $(this).siblings(".tr-second").slideToggle("slow");
});
```

```css
.tr-second {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="tableizer-table">
  <thead>
    <tr class="tableizer-firstrow">
      <th> Процедуры</th>
      <th>Цена</th>
      <th>Ед.</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <div class="parent">
      <tr class="tr-main">
        <td>Blanc Lisse Кубические токи</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="tr-second">
        <td>Blanc Lisse Кубические токи - 10 мин</td>
        <td>4 000,00 руб</td>
        <td>шт</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="tr-second">
        <td>Blanc Lisse Кубические токи - 30 мин</td>
        <td>6 000,00 руб</td>
        <td>шт</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="tr-second">
        <td>Blanc Lisse Кубические токи - дополнительно к процедуре</td>
        <td>4 000,00 руб</td>
        <td>шт</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="tr-second">
        <td>Blanc Lisse Кубические токи - мгновенный лифтинг</td>
        <td>6 000,00 руб</td>
        <td>шт</td>
      </tr>
    </div>
    <div class="parent">
      <tr class="tr-main">
        <td>Candela Удаление пор</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="tr-second">
        <td>Candela Удаление пор - нос</td>
        <td>7 560,00 руб</td>
        <td>шт</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="tr-second">
        <td>Candela Удаление пор - Т-зона</td>
        <td>15 120,00 руб</td>
        <td>шт</td>
      </tr>
    </div>
    <div class="parent">
      <tr class="tr-main">
        <td>Endospheres Therapy (Эндосфера)</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="tr-second">
        <td>Endospheres Therapy (Эндосфера) Тело 1 процедура</td>
        <td>8 500,00 руб</td>
        <td>шт</td>
      </tr>
    </div>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Your table markup is invalid: you cannot have `<div>` inside `<tbody>` as a direct descendant.

Comment: I think your problem might be that you have several rows with the class `tr-main` therefore your selector `$(".tr-main")` acts on all of them at the same time.

Comment: script is correct (look at the example script)
https://webkab.ru/demo/toggle.html

Comment: @Terry in which element can i put <tr> ?

Comment: @secan no, the issue is that all of the `.tr-second` are all siblings of each `.tr-main`.  The `$(".tr-main")` is only to configure the event handler - within the event, `$(this)` refers to the tr-main that was clicked on.

Comment: @freedomn-m as invalid as it is from the markup point of view, wouldn't the presence of the surrounding `<div>` prevent that? Wouldn't `.tr-second` rows be siblings only of the `.tr-main` row which is in the same `<div>`?

Comment: @secan that appears to have been OPs thinking as well - but no, because the `div` is not part of the table - when rendered, the divs are rendered *outside* the table (inspect element to confirm) - so only `tr`s are in the (one) `tbody` in OPs code, so `.siblings("tr")` gets all of them across all groups.

Comment: @freedomn-m I never noticed that behavior; thank you very much for pointing it out. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As previous stated, `div` is not a valid child of `tbody`, so your `.siblings` selects all the `.tr-second` rows across the whole table.

If you do element inspect on the table with divs, you'll see them all outside the table.

Instead, you can replace your `div`s with `<tbody>` elements, thus grouping the tr-main / tr-seconds as intended (with no other change to your js)

```js
$(".tr-main").click(function() {
  $(this).siblings(".tr-second").slideToggle("slow");
});
```

```css
.tr-second {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="tableizer-table">
<thead>
<tr class="tableizer-firstrow"><th>        Процедуры</th><th>Цена</th><th>Ед.</th></tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
 <tr class="tr-main"><td>Blanc Lisse Кубические токи</td><td></td><td></td></tr>
 <tr class="tr-second"><td>Blanc Lisse Кубические токи - 10 мин</td><td>4 000,00 руб</td><td>шт</td></tr>
 <tr class="tr-second"><td>Blanc Lisse Кубические токи - 30 мин</td><td>6 000,00 руб</td><td>шт</td></tr>
 <tr class="tr-second"><td>Blanc Lisse Кубические токи - дополнительно к процедуре</td><td>4 000,00 руб</td><td>шт</td></tr>
 <tr class="tr-second"><td>Blanc Lisse Кубические токи - мгновенный лифтинг</td><td>6 000,00 руб</td><td>шт</td></tr>
</tbody>
<tbody>
 <tr class="tr-main"><td>Candela Удаление пор</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr class="tr-second"><td>Candela Удаление пор - нос</td><td>7 560,00 руб</td><td>шт</td></tr>
 <tr class="tr-second"><td>Candela Удаление пор - Т-зона</td><td>15 120,00 руб</td><td>шт</td></tr>
</tbody>
<tbody>
 <tr class="tr-main"><td>Endospheres Therapy (Эндосфера)</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr class="tr-second"><td>Endospheres Therapy (Эндосфера) Тело 1 процедура</td><td>8 500,00 руб</td><td>шт</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Note that (in Chrome at least) you can't `slide` a `tr` so your `.slideToggle` is the same as `.toggle` but with a delay on hide; but that's a separate issue.

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment, you shouldn't be using `<div>` elements as a immediate descendant (or *child*, see debate in comments) of `<tbody>`, since that is semantically invalid. You don't need those anyway.

You can use [`.nextUntil()`](https://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/), which allows you to match the siblings of your `.tr-main` element until the next one, i.e.: `$(this).nextUntil(".tr-main")`. See proof-of-concept example below:

```js
$(".tr-main").click(function() {
  $(this).nextUntil(".tr-main").toggle();
});
```

```css
.tr-second {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="tableizer-table">
  <thead>
    <tr class="tableizer-firstrow">
      <th> Процедуры</th>
      <th>Цена</th>
      <th>Ед.</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="tr-main">
      <td>Blanc Lisse Кубические токи</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr-second">
      <td>Blanc Lisse Кубические токи - 10 мин</td>
      <td>4 000,00 руб</td>
      <td>шт</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr-second">
      <td>Blanc Lisse Кубические токи - 30 мин</td>
      <td>6 000,00 руб</td>
      <td>шт</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr-second">
      <td>Blanc Lisse Кубические токи - дополнительно к процедуре</td>
      <td>4 000,00 руб</td>
      <td>шт</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr-second">
      <td>Blanc Lisse Кубические токи - мгновенный лифтинг</td>
      <td>6 000,00 руб</td>
      <td>шт</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr-main">
      <td>Candela Удаление пор</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr-second">
      <td>Candela Удаление пор - нос</td>
      <td>7 560,00 руб</td>
      <td>шт</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr-second">
      <td>Candela Удаление пор - Т-зона</td>
      <td>15 120,00 руб</td>
      <td>шт</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr-main">
      <td>Endospheres Therapy (Эндосфера)</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr-second">
      <td>Endospheres Therapy (Эндосфера) Тело 1 процедура</td>
      <td>8 500,00 руб</td>
      <td>шт</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: you are awesome !

Comment: @Quentin A descendant can be direct or indirect. A child is a direct descendant. Source: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/d/descendant/

Comment: @Terry — A child is a child. A descendant is a child, grandchild, great-grandchild, etc. The term "direct" makes no sense in this context because the metaphor comes from genealogy and the term "direct" only comes in to effect when you start dealing with marriage which doesn't exist in a DOM tree. Your reference's use of the term "direct" is just as nonsensical. It isn't used in the HTML, CSS, or DOM specifications.

Comment: @terry there's no mention of "direct descendant" in your link.  :)

Comment: Tone policing and pointing out that I didn't comment on a question I hadn't seen is not the counterargument you seem to think it is.

Comment: Now I'm wondering what an "indirect descendent" would be in the context of DOM elements - a parent's sibling's child?  `$(this).cousins()` ? :)

Comment: @freedomn-m Perhaps "immediate descendant" would be a better way to describe it?

Answer (score 0):

**works** perfectly as your request. More stable and responsive.
**Run the code snippet :**

```js
$(".tr-main").click(function () {
  $(this).nextUntil(".tr-main").toggle(200);
});
```

```css
.tr-second{
  background:yellow;
}
.tr-main{
  background:red;
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table class="tableizer-table" border>
    <thead>
        <tr class="tableizer-firstrow">
            <th>Процедуры</th>
            <th>Цена</th>
            <th>Ед.</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="tr-main">
            <td>Blanc Lisse Кубические токи</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="tr-second">
            <td>Blanc Lisse Кубические токи - 10 мин</td>
            <td>4 000,00 руб</td><td>шт</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="tr-second">
            <td>Blanc Lisse Кубические токи - 30 мин</td>
            <td>6 000,00 руб</td><td>шт</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="tr-second">
            <td>Blanc Lisse Кубические токи - дополнительно к процедуре</td>
            <td>4 000,00 руб</td>
            <td>шт</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="tr-second">
            <td>Blanc Lisse Кубические токи - мгновенный лифтинг</td><td>6 000,00 руб</td>
            <td>шт</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="tr-main">
            <td>Candela Удаление пор</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="tr-second">
            <td>Candela Удаление пор - нос</td>
            <td>7 560,00 руб</td><td>шт</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="tr-second">
            <td>Candela Удаление пор - Т-зона</td>
            <td>15 120,00 руб</td><td>шт</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="tr-main">
            <td>Endospheres Therapy (Эндосфера)</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="tr-second">
            <td>Endospheres Therapy (Эндосфера) Тело 1 процедура</td>
            <td>8 500,00 руб</td><td>шт</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```